# PrintList function is not working properly

Tags: c, list

I'm working on a List program for my course and it seems to be working correctly so far, the only thing that is acting weird is the PrintList function. Let's say I compile the program and push one number (e.g. 4) in the first node and then print the list, the output is: **[4]->[0]->NULL** even if I didn't add another node with 0 as data. Sorry in advance if this is a stupid question, here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node NODE;

void PrintList(NODE *);
void Push(NODE **, int );
void Insert(NODE *, int );
void Append(NODE **, int );
void Delete(NODE **, int );
void Reverse(NODE **);

int main(){
    NODE *head, *temp;

    head=malloc(sizeof(NODE *));
    if(head==NULL){
        puts("Cannot allocate memory");
    }

    int i, t;
    int x;
    while(1){
        printf("Insert choice:\n1. Print List\n2. Push\n3. Insert\n4. 
    Append\n5. Delete\n6. Reverse\n\nEnter any other number to exit.");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        switch(x){
            case 1: 
                PrintList(head);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\nInsert data to push: ");
                scanf("%d", &i);

                Push(&head, i);
                PrintList(head);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\nInsert data to insert: ");
                scanf("%d", &i);

                printf("\nInsert data of previous node: ");
                scanf("%d", &t);

                temp=head;
                while(temp->data!=t){
                    temp=temp->next;
                }

                Insert(temp, i);
                PrintList(head);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("\nInsert data to append: ");
                scanf("%d", &i);

                Append(&head, i);
                PrintList(head);
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("\nInsert value of node to delete: ");
                scanf("%d", &i);

                Delete(&head, i);
                PrintList(head);
                break;
            case 6:
                Reverse(&head);
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nExiting the program.");
                exit(1);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void PrintList(NODE *n){
    while(n!=NULL){
        printf("[%d]->", n->data);
        n=n->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n\n");
    return;
}

void Push(NODE **headptr, int d){
    NODE *newnode;

    newnode=malloc(sizeof(NODE *));
    if(newnode==NULL){
        puts("\nCannot allocate memory\n");
    }

    newnode->next=(*headptr);
    newnode->data=d;
    (*headptr)=newnode;
    return;
}

void Insert(NODE *prev, int d){
    NODE *newnode;

    newnode=malloc(sizeof(NODE *));
    if(newnode==NULL){
        puts("\nCannot allocate memory\n");
    }

    newnode->next=prev->next;
    newnode->data=d;
    prev->next=newnode;
    return;
}

void Append(NODE **headptr, int d){
    NODE *newnode, *cursor;

    newnode=malloc(sizeof(NODE *));
    if(newnode==NULL){
        puts("\nCannot allocate memory\n");
    }

    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->data=d;

    if((*headptr)==NULL){
        (*headptr)=newnode;
        return;
    }
    else{
        cursor=(*headptr);
        while(cursor->next!=NULL){
            cursor=cursor->next;
        }

        cursor->next=newnode;
        return;
    }
}

void Delete(NODE **headptr, int d){
    if((*headptr)==NULL){
        puts("List is empty");
        return;
    }
    else{
        NODE *temp=NULL, *cursor;
        cursor=(*headptr);

        while(cursor->data!=d){
            temp=cursor;
            cursor=cursor->next;
        }

        temp->next=cursor->next;
        free(cursor);

        return;
    }
}

void Reverse(NODE **headptr){
    if((*headptr)==NULL){
        puts("List is empty");
        return;
    }
    else{
        NODE *prev=NULL, *current=(*headptr), *next;

        while(current!=NULL){
            next=current->next;
            current->next=prev;
            prev=current;
            current=next;
        }

        (*headptr)=prev;
        return;
    }
}
```

Edit: feel free to give me any suggestion to the code.

Comment: 1) `malloc(sizeof(NODE *))` --> `malloc(sizeof(NODE))`

Comment: In `main` you create `head` - that's one node. Then in `push` you create another - that's two nodes.

Comment: ...or `newnode=malloc(sizeof(NODE *));` ==> `newnode=malloc(sizeof *newnode);` because your version allocated memory for the pointer, not what it is pointing to.

Comment: Right, I forgot about allocating memory for head too, thanks!

Comment: 2) `head=malloc(sizeof(NODE *));
    if(head==NULL){
        puts("Cannot allocate memory");
    }` --> `head = NULL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems

The first one is pointed by @BLUEPIXY, you are reserving space with a wrong size:

```
malloc(sizeof(NODE *)); /* The size of a pointer to the object */
```

should be

```
malloc(sizeof(NODE)) /* The size of the object */
```

And in the first call to `Push()` you are assigning the address of an uninitialized pointer:

```
newnode->next=(*headptr); /* (*headptr) contains garbage at this point */
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to change all

```
head=malloc(sizeof(NODE*));
```

to

```
head=malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

and program work's correctly.

---

```
printf("%zu", sizeof(NODE));    // 16 B -- depends on padding
printf("%zu", sizeof(NODE*));   // 8  B -- depends on x64/x86 system
```

You are initializing pointer, but you want that pointer to point on `NODE` object which has size `sizeof(NODE)`, instead of that you are you are allocating `sizeof(NODE*)` which is sizeof pointer on your system. If you have `64bit` system, then its `8B`, else `4B`. Now you are trying to store object which has `16B`'s to location of `8B`'s and it has undefined behavior.